# Using sops together with terragrunt

Tags: azure-keyvault, terragrunt, mozilla-sops

I know this is a bit of a generic question but I am entirely new to this and don't know where to find information regarding this, in the repo I found (https://github.com/mozilla/sops) I could not find much about this. I have a bit of trouble to understand how to use sops together with terragrunt to connect to azure key vault.

I have got this example here from an existing codebase (all details in this example have been changed) and would like to understand what I need to do (what I can maybe even leave out) and where to get the information from to connect to my azure key vault using sops (I have set some questions under the values in the code):

```
subscription_id: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:m+...0nlN8=,tag:MmeuD/wk...qw==,type:str] 
--> how do I get subscription_id into this data:... format? What is iv? Where and how do I get this tag information?
client_id: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:nbV...m9HKZ,iv:pxI0Tq...6l8sYo=,tag:A2...o1uc/nN+...8o==,type:str]
--> same here, how do I get client_id into this data:... format?
client_secret: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:cO...qL/4/wc...qzYa1,iv:MTT...jlFE=,tag:uP...t/Ax1...3EA==,type:str]
--> same here, how do I get client_secret into this data:... format?
sops:
kms: []
gcp_kms: []
azure_kv:
    - vault_url: https://sandbox.vault.azure.net
      name: sandbox
      version: 
      --> where do I get version info from?
      created_at: "2021-12-02T15:39:18Z"
      --> where do I get this information from?
      enc: qrN...2DYx7K0ERc2DbEMH1Cm6NTqjAj4Nh4_iSKnXYXm
     --> what is this enc value and where do I get it from?
hc_vault: []
age: []
lastmodified: "2022-02-08T15:39:19Z"
--> Where do I get this info from?
mac: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:sjROymjv2G...1Bx3o0Nn7zxu8=,iv:x+HkkWLI...mr1btig=,tag:6x07...6q==,type:str]
--> What is this value for and where do I get it from?
pgp: []
unencrypted_suffix: _unencrypted
version: 3.7.1
```

Any help on what to change and add to connect to azure key vault using sops is much appreciated!